# I'm applying for Schengen Visa, while working remotely. Is it Legal?

Tags: working-visas, germany, schengen, indian-citizens, german-citizens

I work remotely from India for a UK based company and have been staying in India. I am planning to go as soon as possible now because I want to keep travelling (only this time outside India) while working remotely to support my expenses each month.

I haven't travelled outside my home country before. I'm applying for a tourist visa (Schengen) so that I can visit my friend in Germany. My question is, is it OK for me to say that I am working remotely for a company, while I live in India, pay my taxes in India (it has only been 2 months since I'm working for the company, so I can't produce adequate data from my bank account statement for at least past 3-6 months, before this I was just doing gigs here and there(non-taxable)). I want to find a tourist visa for germany.

So what are the complications here and how can I resolve this?
If not, what's the best way to deal with this?
Thanks.

Comment: The best way is to instruct a fee-earning Schengen specialist; like kingsley napley or similar. They do not do this work for free however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since UK doesn't come under Schengen area you are good. Be sure to show adequate employment proof and a detailed itinerary with focus on your return to continue your work in India.

I had applied for a Schengen visa and got rejected the first time around because I didn't produce any proof of my then vocation (pursuing a full time master's degree in India) and since I said I was unemployed + traveling alone, all the red flags for illegal immigrant checked right.

Schengen visa countries are interested in your legal reasons tying your return to your home country so they don't have to deal with another illegal immigrant.

Comment: I got your point, but you know I started working since July so can't produce ITR or sufficient bank balance. As I've started to work remotely this might be perceived as a fact that I will work from Germany as well, which is illegal.
The situation is now that I've started to working remotely, can manage my expenses I can visit my GF in Germany (a German). I want to apply for a 90days visa.
What is the best way to approach it? I was thinking to say that my father sponsors my expenses, but in reality, I'll be working remotely (only this time from Germany) to manage my expenses.

Comment: Release add these updates to your question by editing it.